# How can i use an object with touch/drag move?

Tags: android, button, touch, move, drag

An exam:http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/simple-moving-object-with-touch-events.html How can i this imagebutton or normal button click together drag/touch move?If we end touch/drag move and we want button click button text "Hello World".